# DateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH_mm_ss") resulted in incorrect 'year' component only on certain Japanese laptops

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

We have a WPF application that is used by users across the world.
We have the below date conversation in the code.

```
DateTime dt = <some date time value>;

var formattedDateTime = (dt.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH_mm_ss"));
```

This line is giving incorrect results in a few Japanese laptops with a Japanese culture set.

For example, if the dt value is {2019/09/11 14:42:47}:

- 'formattedDateTime' output in few Japanese laptops: 01.09.11-14_42_47
- 'formattedDateTime' output in all other cultures: 2019.09.11-14_42_47

I think some of the Japanese culture settings on these laptops are causing this issue. But I couldn't sort out what is that setting.
Also, I think adding CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to the DateTime.ToString() may solve this issue.

Any idea what setting is causing this issue?

Comment: "Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and culture-specific format information.", see: [ToString(String, IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_). Or, in more words, specify the second parameter.

Comment: is my code working ?

Comment: So the claim is that `yyyy` produces 01 for 2019 in some cases in Japan? Does it produce 02 for 2020?

Comment: @Luuk specifying the second parameter to CultureInfo.InvariantCulture might fix the issue. But that needs a new release. Please note that this issue is only on a handful of Japanese laptops. I am trying to understand what Culture setting is causing this issue so that we can ask the users to modify the setting and retry.

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, It produces 02 for 2020 and 03 for 2021.

Comment: 2019 was the first year of 令和, so it seems to be producing the Japanese Emperor year.

Comment: Presumably the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is using the [`JapaneseCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.japanesecalendar?view=net-5.0) calendar class, rather than the [`GregorianCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar?view=net-5.0) one.

Comment: @T.Tom: You might still need to add the culture, because 'some day' you will (hopefully) release a new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said, on certain machines the Japanese culture is defaulting to using the [Japanese calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.japanesecalendar?view=net-5.0) rather than the [Gregorian calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar?view=net-5.0).

The Japanese calendar uses eras based on the reign of the Emperor, such that:

- Showa (昭和) goes from 1926/12/25 - 1989/01/07
- Heisei (平成) goes from 1989/01/08 - 2019/04/30
- Reiwa (令和) goes from 2019/05/01 - present

We can test this in code:

```
var jpCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-jp");
jpCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new JapaneseCalendar();
// output: 昭和 63/05/11
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1988, 05, 11).ToString("g yyyy/MM/dd", jpCulture));
// output: 平成 20/05/11
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008, 05, 11).ToString("g yyyy/MM/dd", jpCulture));
// output: 平成 31/04/30
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2019, 04, 30).ToString("g yyyy/MM/dd", jpCulture));
// output: 令和 01/05/01
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2019, 05, 01).ToString("g yyyy/MM/dd", jpCulture));
```

Your options here are:

1. Do as Robyn suggests and have the user change their OS calendar setting to Gregorian (the user's current setting will be 和暦 - Japanese calendar - and needs to be changed to 西暦 - Western calendar).

[image]

2. Explicitly format the date using the Invariant culture:

```cs
string myDateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

3. At startup, enforce a culture that uses the Gregorian calendar.
   Be aware that with this option, other code is free to change the "current" culture later on in the execution of your program.

```cs
CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

4. Create a wrapper method that wraps around the `ToString` functionality and adds the era if the current calendar isn't Gregorian:

```cs
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringYMDWithEra(this DateTime dt)
    {
        string formatString = (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar is GregorianCalendar) 
            ? "yyyy/MM/dd"
            : "gyyyy/MM/dd";
        return dt.ToString(formatString);           
    }
}
```

Usage: `string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToStringYMDWithEra();`

Note that Japanese users will implicitly understand the Japanese calendar with the era attached. Everything from forms to register with a doctor to anything official uses the Japanese calendar system. For example, my driving licence has my birth year (1988) as 昭和63.

Answer (score 3):

Some of your users have their Windows date format set to use the Japansese calendar, in which 2019 is year 1 of the Reiwa era. They may be able to work around your issue by going into the Windows control panel and either changing their date format to one of the options that shows the Gregorian year ("ggy" instead of "y") or else change their calendar type from Japanese to Gregorian.

Answer (score -2):

```
const string culture = "ja-JP";
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(culture);
var formattedDateTime = (dt.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH_mm_ss" , info));
```